# Check constraint on last max

Tags: postgresql, constraints

How do I make a check constraint against the last maximum value in a field? For example, in the following:

```
CREATE TABLE prisoner (
    prisoner_id    SERIAL4 PRIMARY KEY,
    name           TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(length(name) <= 256)
);

CREATE TABLE meals (
    prisoner_id       INT4 REFERENCES prisoner,
    last_meal_time    TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now()        
);
```

How I ensure that `last_meal_time` is always `>=` than the last maximum `last_meal_time` for the given `prisoner_id`? In other words, I won't be able to retroactively feed any given prisoner another meal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions in a check constraints like:

```
create table t(id serial, p int, ts timestamp);

create function t_max_time(p_id int) returns timestamp as $$ select max(ts) from t where p = p_id $$ language sql;

alter table t add constraint t_ts_check check (ts >= t_max_time(p));

-- Thanks to Clodoaldo Neto attention,
-- To prevent changes in other concurrent transactions while our transaction is active we can lock table for exclusive editing like:
lock table t in exclusive mode nowait;
-- It locks table or raises exception if table already locked by another transaction

insert into t(p, ts) values (1, '2016-02-02 10:10:10'), (1, '2016-02-02 11:11:11'); -- It works

insert into t(p, ts) values (1, '2016-02-02 09:09:09'); -- Constraint violation
```

Comment: Fails if the inserts happen in concurrent transactions.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto You are right and the simplest way to solve it is using table locking: `lock table t in exclusive mode nowait;` BTW there are another questions about behavior of app on editing existing rows etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set the primary key:

```
create table meals (
    prisoner_id int4 references prisoner,
    last_meal_time timestamp with time zone not null default clock_timestamp(),
    primary key (prisoner_id, last_meal_time)
);
```

Notice that it is [`clock_timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

And always insert the default value:

```
insert into meals (prisoner_id) values (1);
```

Comment: So you assume that `clock_timestamp()` will always return unique timestamps. I don't think this is guaranteed.

Comment: @TmTron It is not guaranteed. If a very unlikely collision occurs than a retrial is necessary.